# Remove Attribute names from Json string

Tags: javascript, substring

Hi lets say I have a JSON string which represent a record in a grid containing 3 columns `Id, Name, Status`. I'm currently writing some JavaScript logic where you can filter the rows of data by typing some text in the text box. The filter will be applied to data in all columns. So if I type "James" Record 1 below will be returned an if I type None Record 1 and 2 will be returned. The problem is if I type Id, Name, or Status which is not the data but the attribute names, all records are always returned.

```
Record 1
{
    Id: 1,
    Name: "James",
    Status: "None"
}

Record 2
{
    Id: 2,
    Name: "Paul",
    Status: "None"
}
```

How can I modify a JSON string so that

```
{ Id: 2, Name: "Paul", Status: "None"}
```

will become

```
{ 2, "Paul", "None"}
```

Comment: Simple. `for(var prop in a){
if(a.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
console.log(a[prop])
}
}` you may get it by pushing `a[prop]` to an empty object or array.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear (and I'm afraid Matthias' edit made that matter worse).

`{ Id: 1, Name: "James", Status: "None" }` is not a valid JSON string, but it *is* a valid Javascript object. JSON strings need to have their values within quotes.

If you are indeed dealing with a JSON string, with quoted properties, and you simply want the output you've requested, you could do something like this:

```
var person = '{ "Id": 1, "Name": "James", "Status": "None" }';
person = person.replace(/\s*"[^"]+"\s*:/g,"");
// > person = '{ 1, "James", "None" }'
```

If you are dealing with a Javascript object, a simple way of getting the values without the property names would be to do something like this:

```
var person = { Id: 1, Name: "James", Status: "None" };
person = Object.keys(person).map(function(k) { return person[k] }).join(',');
// > person = '1,James,None'
```

Both options will give you a string that you could search for just the values you're interested in. In the latter scenario, you'd need to add some formatting to turn the outcome into exactly what you have requested, but then given the question I'm assuming presentation is not a big deal.

However, if at all possible, I think your code would much more closely match your intentions if you instead modified the search algorithm to inspect values and not entire objects. You haven't shown us any of the code doing the searching, though, so I can't really add suggestions for that at this point.